# Right location and way for wiring data and util functions

Tags: loopbackjs

I am migrating an application from sails.js to loopback and have a newbie question for all loopback gurus out there.

I have two set of functions which I access through the application.

1. Data functions - common functions used between modules for getting certain config and object properties
2. Util function - functions for string, object, array and data manipulations.

In all there are about 15 data and 25 util functions in current application

I have three questions on writing storing there functions ..

1. Is server/middleware the right location for writing these functions
2. Provided the functions are stored in server/middleware location, is "inital:after" phase calling these functions
3. I have noticed you cannot store multiple middleware functions in a single file and each function needs to be written separately and  registered with the middleware. Do I need to create separate files for each function if the functions get stored in the middleware ? I would idealy like to group the function in few files as possible.

Thank you for reading the post. The answers would be very helpful for folks who are migrating from other platforms in awesome loopback.

Answer (score 0):

An idea for shared functions and data may be to expose them to the `loopbackContext` object thro middleware in a bootscript.

```
let loopback = require('loopback')
app.use(function setContextMethods(req,res,next) {
  var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext()
  if (ctx) {
    ctx.set('myData', data)
  }
}
```

this data/methods can be accessed during requests using the context object (their availability depends on the middleware slot you place them like session:after session:before etc).

Example to accessThem:

```
User.afterRemote('login', function (context, token, next) {
  context.get('myData')
}
```

This allows you to expose data/ methods for each request (and configure them for example if the user is logged or not), other than that you can always place them in a utils.js file.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it's an idea.